# How to create Interface to read Struct in mapping?

Tags: solidity, struct, interfaces

There are 2 contracts `A` and `B`.

`A` has a mapping which returns `Struct`:

`mapping (bytes32 => Cup)  public  cups;`

How can we read the `cups` mapping in contract `B`?

Following code doesn't work for sure:

```
interface CupsInteraface {
    function cups(bytes32 cup) external returns (Struct);
}
```

Comment: Providing more context will help to answer your question. Could you clarify the structure of both contracts, how they should interact?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in a stable version of solidity, but possible in experimental

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

interface CupInteraface {
    struct S {
        bytes32 s;
    }
    function get(bytes32 cup) external returns (S memory);
}

contract Cup is CupInteraface {
    mapping(bytes32 => S) private _cups;

    constructor(bytes32 cup) public {
        _cups[cup] = S(cup);
    }

    function get(bytes32 cup) public returns (S memory) {
        return _cups[cup];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, [it's not possible to return structs](https://github.com/BANKEX/web3swift/issues/33) in solidity. 
The most obvious workaround would be to make functions that return individual elements of a specific struct, like, assuming a cup has a title:

```
function cup_title(bytes32 cup) external returns (string){
   return cups[cup].title
}
```

And repeat that for every property.

Or, have just one function that [returns multiple values](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5ew2jh/how_can_i_get_multiple_returned_values_in_solidity/) from it (ie: all the attributes of the struct).

Or, [use the Seriality library](https://github.com/pouladzade/Seriality).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using return type from Interface itself. While calling the function in contract B define the return type Interface.struct.

Consider below example:

```
// Main contract which have struct
contract A {
    struct cup{
        uint value1;
        uint value2;
    }

    mapping(uint=>cup) public cups;

    // Method to add cup struct in mapping.
    function addCup(uint _key, uint _value1, uint _value2) public{
        cups[_key] = cup(_value1, _value2);
    }
}

// Interface with struct and Mapping signature function
interface IA {
    // Struct of main contract A
    struct cup{
        uint value1;
        uint value2;
    }

    // Function signature for mapping
    function cups(uint key) view external returns (cup memory);
}

// Secondary contract to access data from main contract
contract B{
    function getCup(uint key, address _A) view public returns (IA.cup memory) {
        IA.cup memory _cup = IA(_A).cups(key);
        return _cup;
    }
}
```

Please check the attached screenshot of output from remix as well.
[image]

**Note:** *This is for demo purpose only, The best implementation strategy is to implement Interface IA in contract A and use same struct of interface in contract A and contract B from Interface IA.*

Answer (score 0):

For the Interface, Don't create the struct in the interface
instead use a library that way its abstracted and reusable

```
library StructLib {
    // Struct of main contract A
    struct cup{
        uint value1;
        uint value2;
    }
}
interface IA {
    // Function signature for mapping
    function cups(uint key) view external returns (StructLib.cup memory);
}

contract B{
    function getCup(uint key, address _A) view public returns (StructLib.cup memory) {
        StructLib.cup memory _cup = IA(_A).cups(key);
        return _cup;
    }
}
```

Comment: This only compiles since solc v0.8, the syntax isn't available in older versions.